# no duplicate function for a lottery program

Tags: c++, arrays

right now im trying to make a function that checks to see if the user’s selection is already in the array , and if it does itll tell you to choose a diff number. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
bool CheckNumberIsValid()
{
   for(int i = 0 ; i < array_length; ++i)
   {
      if(array[i] == user_selection)
         return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

That should give you a clue, at least.

Comment: why brutal force? try figuring out if the array is sorted first, and if so, a binary search will be much more efficient

Comment: @amit: Because it's a user interface. This function already works thousands of times faster than it has to.

Comment: Given the context of the question and the fact that it includes "homework" as a tag, I think this is the most straight-forward and therefore appropriate response. A binary search is overkill for what's required here and will probably confuse the hell out of his/her teacher.

Comment: im sorry but i keep getting confused with the (array[i] == user_selection)  what is array[i]

Comment: @paul kee: It's "the array", of course! See your own OP if you don't understand yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `std::find`?  If you get the `end` iterator back, the
value isn't in the array; otherwise, it is.  Or if this is homework, and
you're not allowed to use the standard library, a simple while loop
should do the trick: this is a standard linear search, algorithms for
which can be found anywhere.  (On the other hand, some of the articles
which pop up when searching with Google are pretty bad.  You really
should use the standard implementation:

```
Iterator
find( Iterator begin, Iterator end, ValueType target )
{
    while ( begin != end && *begin != target )
        ++ begin;
    return begin;
}
```

Simple, effective, and proven to work.)

Answer (score 1):

[added *post factum*]Oh, homework tag. Ah well, it won't really benefit you that much then, still - I'll leave my answer since it can be of some use to others browsing through SO.

If you'd need to have lots of unique random numbers in a range - say 45000 random numbers from `0..45100` - then you should see how this is going to get problematic using the approach of:

```
while (size_of_range > v.size()) {
    int n = // get random
    if ( /* n  is not already in  v */ ) {
        v.push_back(n);
    } 
}
```

If the size of the pool and the range you want to get are close, and the pool size is not a very small integer - it'll get harder and harder to get a random number that wasn't already put in the vector/array. 
In that case, you'll be much better of using `std::vector` (in `<vector>`) and `std::random_shuffle` (in `<algorithm>`):

```
unsigned short start = 10; // the minimum value of a pool
unsigned short step = 1; // for 10,11,12,13,14... values in the vector
// initialize the pool of 45100 numbers
std::vector<unsigned long> pool(45100);
for (unsigned long i = 0, j = start; i < pool.size(); ++i, j += step) {
    pool[i] = j;
}
// get 45000 numbers from the pool without repetitions
std::random_shuffle(pool.begin(), pool.end());
return std::vector<unsigned long>(pool.begin(), pool.begin() + 45000);
```

You can obviously use any type, but you'll need to initialize the vector accordingly, so it'd contain all possible values you want.

Note that the memory overhead probably won't really matter if you really need almost all of the numbers in the pool, and you'll get good performance. Using `rand()` and checking will take a lot of time, and if your `RAND_MAX` is equal `32767` then it'd be an infinite loop.
The memory overhead is however noticeable if you only need few of those values. The first approach would usually be faster then.

Answer (score 0):

If it really needs to be the array you need to iterate or use find function from algorithm header. Well, I would suggest you go for putting the numbers in a set as the look up is fast in sets and handy using set::find function

ref: [stl set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the steps (in pseudo-code since this is a homework question) on how you may get around to doing this:

1. Get user to enter a new number.
2. If the number entered is the first, push it to the vector anyway.
3. Sort the contents of the vector in case size is > 1.
4. Ask user to enter the number.
5. Perform a binary search on the contents to see if the number was entered.
6. If number is unique, push it into vector. If not unique, ask again.
7. Go to step 3.

HTH,
Sriram.

Comment: wow - very complicated - what's the point of the sort and binary search - what's a lottery number - 6 numbers as most? a simple iteration will most likely be significantly quicker.

Comment: @Nim: In the absence of any information about the number of such numbers that need to be added, this would be the most general-purpose algorithm. Of course, if you assume that only a very small number of lottery numbers will be added you can lose the sort and search parts.